# Elasticsearch tokenizer to keep (and concatenate) "and"

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I am trying to make an Elasticsearch filter, analyzer and tokenizer to be able to normalize searches like:

- `"henry&william book"` -> `"henrywilliam book"`
- `"henry & william book"` -> `"henrywilliam book"`
- `"henry and william book"` -> `"henrywilliam book"`
- `"henry william book"` -> `"henry william book"`

In other words, I would like to normalize my "and" and "&" queries, but also concatenate the words between them.

I'm thinking of making a tokenizer that breaks `"henry & william book"` into tokens `["henry & william", "book"]`, and then make a character filter that makes the following replacements:

- `" & "` -> `""`
- `" and "` -> `""`
- `"&"` -> `""`

However, this feels a bit hackish. Is there a better way to do it?

The reason I can't just do this entirely in the analyzer/filter phase, is that it runs too late. In my attempts, Elasticsearch has already broken `"henry & william"` into just `["henry", "william"]` before my analyzer/filter runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a clever mix of two character filters that kick in before the tokenizer. The first character filter would map `and` onto `&` and the second character filter would get rid of the `&` and glue the two neighboring tokens together. This mix would also allow you to introduce other replacements, such as `|` and `or` for instance.

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "and": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "and => &"
          ]
        },
        "&": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": """(\w+)(\s*&\s*)(\w+)""",
          "replacement": "$1$3"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my-analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "and", "&"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would yields the following results:

```
POST test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my-analyzer",
  "text": [
    "henry&william book"
  ]
}

Results =>

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "henrywilliam book",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}

POST test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my-analyzer",
  "text": [
    "henry & william book"
  ]
}

Results =>

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "henrywilliam book",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}

POST test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my-analyzer",
  "text": [
    "henry and william book"
  ]
}

Results =>

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "henrywilliam book",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}

POST test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my-analyzer",
  "text": [
    "henry william book"
  ]
}

Results =>

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "henry william book",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a single character filter and and some knowledge of regular expressions. Character filters are used to preprocess the stream of characters before it is passed to the tokenizer.

```json
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "remove_and": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": """\s*(&|\band\b)\s*""",
                    "description": "Removes ands and ampersands"
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "book-analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "remove_and"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- **\s*** optional whitespaces around your expression
- **\b** word boundaries around the 'and', e.g. not to react in c**and**y